# Should I use the Web API when I do not fully embrace REST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a single page app running in desktop browser, tablet browser and maybe phone browser. I am return only JSON from my backend wether it is ASP.NET MVC or Web API.

When I think of Web API or read about it I always hear the words REST/RESTfull. Independently from what REST is I like some features about Web API which I have not in MVC (by default but maybe it can be implemented somehow but I dont want that extra effort...)

- Return HttpStatus codes like 200 for GET or 201 when the Ressource is created. My single page app knows and reacts on this codes.
- Return DTOs directly in the controller and c# classes are automatically serialized to json. With MVC this is not a one-liner. Not dealing with ActionResults.
- Web API is very much designed about 'cool' urls/routing I will also have deep/complex routing on my client.
- My Web API endpoints are just 'ajax callbacks' I do not need REST things like include a self.link in every retrieved ressource etc...

Of course I do not create/modify ressources on a Get request. But I already have been used to this style when I was doing MVC. So I like and will do many REST styles but not because of REST itself rather its common practice.

Should I really design great restfull API`s to use the Web API ? I do not know what is Microsofts recommendation about the Web API or wether they have really a guideline about it...

Comment: By-the-book REST seems to fit a classic CRUD style app situation the best. I've found that when writing reporting or BI type apps, that following the REST rules fully isn't the best fit for me. For example, I use PUT from the request body to handle complex filtering and sorting parameters. In general, you don't need to follow the rules completely, especially outside the CRUD world, but don't get too off track with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience Web API has often been a great help, and rarely a hindrance. If you do it "their way," it saves you a lot of ugly work around serialization/routing/binding. If you don't want to do it "their way," you don't have to. You can extend the routing engine. You can implement your own serialization. You can return raw `JSON` where you see fit. Nothing in Web API forces you to follow the REST concept to a T (trust me I have seen this in action). I haven't heard this complaint before from anyone who has used it - I would suggest you give it a try and see just how far off it really is.

Answer (score 0):

REST is not at all required to use Web API. In fact, it is quite easy to turn on and use session management as well.

In fact, while RESTful approaches have some real advantages, I wouldn't recommend going 100% RESTful. It is simply not possible to make them fully secure without using a third-party authentication provider. We built a fully RESTful prototype and explored many different mechanisms to secure the site. In the end, though, every one had one vulnerability or another (it helps to have a CISSP on staff). So I talked to one of the top security experts at Norton and he agreed that, yes, there is always a way to exploit a fully RESTful, standalone app. Symantec is apparently building a "wrapper" technology that gets around this but it was easier to either go with a third-party authentication provider or just go back to MS-based security using session cookies.